# ImpressPages 4.x HTTPS getUrl BUG

Tags: php, impresspages

We use ImpressPages 4.1.1 on Amazon and some IP core files need a FIX because the string is case sensitive and Amazon returns `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = "On"`:

```
BUG:
C:\wamp\www\bazaar\Codigos\site2\Ip\Request.php (2 hits)
    Line 116:         return (isset($this->_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $this->_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on");
    Line 199:         if (isset($this->_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $this->_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {

FIX:
C:\wamp\www\bazaar\Codigos\site2\Ip\Request.php (2 hits)
Line 116:         return (isset($this->_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && strtolower($this->_SERVER["HTTPS"]) == "on");
Line 199:         if (isset($this->_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && strtolower($this->_SERVER["HTTPS"]) == "on") {

SAME BUG IN:
C:\wamp\www\bazaar\Codigos\site2\Ip\Config.php (1 hit)
Line 68:         if (isset($server['HTTPS']) && $server['HTTPS'] == "on") {

AND:
C:\wamp\www\bazaar\Codigos\site2\Ip\Internal\UrlHelper.php (1 hit)
    Line 18:         if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
```

Comment: So what is your issue here?  From my understanding this appears to be more of a bug report than an actual problem.

Comment: Thank You, Juliano. Fix has been commited.